# How can I add info window in places searchbox

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to add info window to this example 'Places search box' https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox

and info window should be like this example which contains name with google link, address, telephone, rating and website https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-hotelsearch

[image: Need info window like the following image.]

Comment: What have you tried so far, where is your code?

Comment: please check the example link. I am talking about the exact code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically StackOverflow is not used to ask somebody to write code for you. You just need to combine these two examples to get the desired behavior.

That being said, below you can find the merged example, that introduces info windows from the second example to the first example.

```js
var map, places, infoWindow;
      
      function initAutocomplete() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
          zoom: 13,
          mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
        });
        
        infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
          content: document.getElementById('info-content')
        });
        
        places = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

        // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
        var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
        var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

        // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
        map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
          searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
        });

        var markers = [];
        // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
        // more details for that place.
        searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
          var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

          if (places.length == 0) {
            return;
          }

          // Clear out the old markers.
          markers.forEach(function(marker) {
            google.maps.event.clearListeners(marker, 'click');
            marker.setMap(null);
          });
          markers = [];

          // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
          var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
          var count = 0;
          places.forEach(function(place) {
            if (!place.geometry) {
              console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
              return;
            }
            var icon = {
              url: place.icon,
              size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
              origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
              anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
              scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
            };

            // Create a marker for each place.
            markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
              map: map,
              icon: icon,
              title: place.name,
              position: place.geometry.location
            }));
            
            markers[count].placeResult = place;
            
            google.maps.event.addListener(markers[count], 'click', showInfoWindow);

            if (place.geometry.viewport) {
              // Only geocodes have viewport.
              bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
            } else {
              bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
            }
            
            count++;
          });
          map.fitBounds(bounds);
        });
      }
      
      function showInfoWindow() {
        var marker = this;
        places.getDetails({placeId: marker.placeResult.place_id},
            function(place, status) {
              if (status !== google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                return;
              }
              infoWindow.open(map, marker);
              buildIWContent(place);
            });
      }
      
      function buildIWContent(place) {
        document.getElementById('iw-icon').innerHTML = '<img class="hotelIcon" ' +
            'src="' + place.icon + '"/>';
        document.getElementById('iw-url').innerHTML = '<b><a href="' + place.url +
            '">' + place.name + '</a></b>';
        document.getElementById('iw-address').textContent = place.vicinity;

        if (place.formatted_phone_number) {
          document.getElementById('iw-phone-row').style.display = '';
          document.getElementById('iw-phone').textContent =
              place.formatted_phone_number;
        } else {
          document.getElementById('iw-phone-row').style.display = 'none';
        }

        // Assign a five-star rating to the hotel, using a black star ('&#10029;')
        // to indicate the rating the hotel has earned, and a white star ('&#10025;')
        // for the rating points not achieved.
        if (place.rating) {
          var ratingHtml = '';
          for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if (place.rating < (i + 0.5)) {
              ratingHtml += '&#10025;';
            } else {
              ratingHtml += '&#10029;';
            }
          document.getElementById('iw-rating-row').style.display = '';
          document.getElementById('iw-rating').innerHTML = ratingHtml;
          }
        } else {
          document.getElementById('iw-rating-row').style.display = 'none';
        }

        // The regexp isolates the first part of the URL (domain plus subdomain)
        // to give a short URL for displaying in the info window.
        if (place.website) {
          var fullUrl = place.website;
          var website = hostnameRegexp.exec(place.website);
          if (website === null) {
            website = 'http://' + place.website + '/';
            fullUrl = website;
          }
          document.getElementById('iw-website-row').style.display = '';
          document.getElementById('iw-website').textContent = website;
        } else {
          document.getElementById('iw-website-row').style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
```

```css
#map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #description {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }

      #infowindow-content .title {
        font-weight: bold;
      }

      #infowindow-content {
        display: none;
      }

      #map #infowindow-content {
        display: inline;
      }

      .pac-card {
        margin: 10px 10px 0 0;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
      }

      #pac-container {
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        margin-right: 12px;
      }

      .pac-controls {
        display: inline-block;
        padding: 5px 11px;
      }

      .pac-controls label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }

      #pac-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 400px;
      }

      #pac-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
      }

      #title {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        font-size: 25px;
        font-weight: 500;
        padding: 6px 12px;
      }
      #target {
        width: 345px;
      }
      .placeIcon {
        width: 20px;
        height: 34px;
        margin: 4px;
      }
      .hotelIcon {
        width: 24px;
        height: 24px;
      }
```

```html
<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
    <div id="map"></div>
    
    <div style="display: none">
      <div id="info-content">
        <table>
          <tr id="iw-url-row" class="iw_table_row">
            <td id="iw-icon" class="iw_table_icon"></td>
            <td id="iw-url"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="iw-address-row" class="iw_table_row">
            <td class="iw_attribute_name">Address:</td>
            <td id="iw-address"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="iw-phone-row" class="iw_table_row">
            <td class="iw_attribute_name">Telephone:</td>
            <td id="iw-phone"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="iw-rating-row" class="iw_table_row">
            <td class="iw_attribute_name">Rating:</td>
            <td id="iw-rating"></td>
          </tr>
          <tr id="iw-website-row" class="iw_table_row">
            <td class="iw_attribute_name">Website:</td>
            <td id="iw-website"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete"
         async defer></script>
```

You can find this example on jsbin as well: http://jsbin.com/xipagud/edit?html,output

Hope this helps!

Comment: first of all thank very much for the solution. I was trying to merge both example but didn't. Now I got the solution. thank you again and I am sorry for the coding issue. I thought if I write it will be same like the example. for that just provided the sample code URL. I understand what you suggested and will follow in the future.

Comment: hi @xomena , just one thing the website field is always empty. would you able to check?

Comment: bro, having another problem. the infowindow popup position is not perfect like hotel search example. The infowindow popup appearing little right of the map marker.